# Streaming Wine Audio to Twitch

Tags: sound, wine, streaming

I'm trying to steam some Dota 2 (via Wine) casts to Twitch using this shell script I found online:

```
#!/bin/bash

STREAM_KEY="(redacted)"
FPS="30"
INRES="1600x900"
OUTRES="1280x720"
QUAL="medium"

avconv \
  -f x11grab -s $INRES -r "$FPS" -i :0.0 \
  -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse \
  -vcodec libx264 -s $OUTRES -preset $QUAL \
  -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 6 -qscale 3 -b 712000 -bufsize 512k \
  -f flv "rtmp://live.justin.tv/app/$STREAM_KEY"
```

It streams the video fine, but I only get audio from my plugged in microphone and no audio from Dota 2. This wouldn't be terrible if I only cared about getting the sound effects, but I am sometimes co-casting with other people using the built-in voice chat, and since I am not getting any of their audio, it sounds like I am a madman.

I could try and use an external program for voice chat, but I don't really want to force any of my random co-casters to set it up on their end. So I'd like to be able to pipe both the Wine audio and my microphone audio to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a null-sink and two loopback connectors:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink
pactl load-module module-loopback
pactl load-module module-loopback
```

To configure those channels you need the pavucontrol tool (`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`).

- On the Playback tab select "All streams" and redirect the loopback streams to "Null output".
- Then go to the "Recording" tab and also select "All streams". You should see both loopbacks again.
- Set one to "Analog Stereo Internal Audio" (the microphone) and set the other one to "Analog Stereo Internal Audio Monitor" (the audio output).
- After running your script you should see the avconv process in the list on the "Recording" tab. Set it to recording from "Null Output Monitor".

[Soure](http://blog.flipzu.com/2011/02/how-to-mix-voice-and-audio-on-ubuntu.html)